# How to relate two vocabularies in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

I have created two vocabularies, 'subject1' and 'subject2'. Both 'subject1' and 'subject2' have the term 'history paper'.

How  would I relate these two vocabularies? Please help me. I have tried the Hierarchical Select and Taxonomy Tree modules.

Comment: Hey there, I agree with splatio below: it would help to describe what you're trying to achieve by 'relating' the two vocabularies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here, that you're wanting to relate the terms ('History Paper') rather than the vocabularies as I'm not sure that would be easy to accomplish:

You could try adding an [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field to your taxonomy term. This would allow you to cross reference multiple taxonomy terms. It's difficult to know if this will work as you haven't stated what you're trying to achieve by relating these two terms.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal vocabularies are frustratingly well-isolated from each other, so if you want any kind of interaction between terms, you don't have much choice but to use a single vocabulary. I'm sure many modules have been written to address this, but I haven't yet found any that are any good.

If the two vocabularies are so similar that they have related terms (and given what little information you've offered, I can't imagine many well-structured scenarios that require a split between individual subjects at this level), I recommend you merge them into one, eg "Subject" and use a hierarchical structure within the new vocab to depict the separation between subject1 and subject2.